# How to correctly convert MIDI ticks to milliseconds?

Tags: python, midi

I'm trying to convert MIDI ticks/delta time to milliseconds and have found a few helpful resources already:

1. [MIDI Delta Time Ticks to Seconds](http://www.lastrayofhope.co.uk/2009/12/23/midi-delta-time-ticks-to-seconds/2/)
2. [How to convert midi timeline into the actual timeline that should be played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288593/how-to-convert-midi-timeline-into-the-actual-timeline-that-should-be-played/5297236#5297236)
3. [MIDI Time Code spec](http://web.archive.org/web/20110629053759/http://web.media.mit.edu/~meyers/mcgill/multimedia/senior_project/MTC.html)
4. [MTC](http://web.archive.org/web/20111211004923/http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/mtc.htm)

The problem is I don't think I'm using this information correctly.
I've tried applying the formula Nik expanded:

```
[  1 min    60 sec   1 beat     Z clocks ]
| ------- * ------ * -------- * -------- | = seconds
[ X beats   1 min    Y clocks       1    ]
```

using the metadata from [this test MIDI file](http://lifesine.eu/so/Bee_Gees_-_Stayin_Alive-Voice.mid):

```
<meta message set_tempo tempo=576923 time=0>
<meta message key_signature key='Ab' time=0>
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=24 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=8 time=0>
```

Like so:

```
self.toSeconds = 60.0 * self.t[0][2].clocks_per_click / (self.t[0][0].tempo * self.t[0][2].denominator) * 10
```

This initially looks ok, but then it seems to drift.
Here is a basic runnable example using [Mido](https://mido.readthedocs.org/en/latest/midi_files.html#meta-messages) and [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs) (assuming pygame plays back correctly):

```
import threading

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from mido import MidiFile,MetaMessage

music_file = "Bee_Gees_-_Stayin_Alive-Voice.mid"

#audio setup
freq = 44100    # audio CD quality
bitsize = -16   # unsigned 16 bit
channels = 2    # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
buffer = 1024    # number of samples
pygame.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.8)


class MIDIPlayer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,music_file):
        try:
            #MIDI parsing
            self.mid = MidiFile(music_file)
            self.t = self.mid.tracks

            for i, track in enumerate(self.mid.tracks):
                print('Track {}: {}'.format(i, track.name))
                for message in track:
                    if isinstance(message, MetaMessage):
                        if message.type == 'time_signature' or message.type == 'set_tempo' or message.type == 'key_signature':
                            print message

            self.t0 = self.t[0][3:len(self.t[0])-1]
            self.t0l = len(self.t0)
            self.toSeconds = 60.0 * self.t[0][2].clocks_per_click / (self.t[0][0].tempo * self.t[0][2].denominator) * 10
            print "self.toSeconds",self.toSeconds
            #timing setup
            self.event_id = 0
            self.now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.play_music(music_file)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(1000)
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            raise SystemExit

    def play_music(self,music_file):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)
            print "Music file %s loaded!" % music_file
        except pygame.error:
            print "File %s not found! (%s)" % (music_file, pygame.get_error())
            return
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            # check if playback has finished
            millis = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            deltaMillis = self.t0[self.event_id].time * self.toSeconds * 1000
            # print millis,deltaMillis
            if millis - self.now >= deltaMillis:
                print self.t0[self.event_id].text
                self.event_id = (self.event_id + 1) % self.t0l
                self.now = millis
            clock.tick(30)

MIDIPlayer(music_file)
```

What the above code should do is print the correct lyric at the correct time based on the midi file, yet it drifts over time.

What's the correct way of converting MIDI delta time to seconds/milliseconds ?

**Update**

Based on CL's helpful answer I've updated the code to use **ticks_per_beat** from the header. Since there is a single `set_tempo` meta message, I am using this value throughout:

```
import threading

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from mido import MidiFile,MetaMessage

music_file = "Bee_Gees_-_Stayin_Alive-Voice.mid"

#audio setup
freq = 44100    # audio CD quality
bitsize = -16   # unsigned 16 bit
channels = 2    # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
buffer = 1024    # number of samples
pygame.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.8)


class MIDIPlayer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,music_file):
        try:
            #MIDI parsing
            self.mid = MidiFile(music_file)
            self.t = self.mid.tracks

            for i, track in enumerate(self.mid.tracks):
                print('Track {}: {}'.format(i, track.name))
                for message in track:
                    # print message
                    if isinstance(message, MetaMessage):
                        if message.type == 'time_signature' or message.type == 'set_tempo' or message.type == 'key_signature' or message.type == 'ticks_per_beat':
                            print message

            self.t0 = self.t[0][3:len(self.t[0])-1]
            self.t0l = len(self.t0)
            self.toSeconds = 60.0 * self.t[0][2].clocks_per_click / (self.t[0][0].tempo * self.t[0][2].denominator) * 10
            print "self.toSeconds",self.toSeconds

            # append delta delays in milliseconds
            self.delays = []

            tempo = self.t[0][0].tempo
            ticks_per_beat = self.mid.ticks_per_beat

            last_event_ticks = 0
            microseconds = 0

            for event in self.t0:
                delta_ticks = event.time - last_event_ticks
                last_event_ticks = event.time
                delta_microseconds = tempo * delta_ticks / ticks_per_beat
                microseconds += delta_microseconds
                print event.text,microseconds/1000000.0
                self.delays.append(microseconds/1000)

            #timing setup
            self.event_id = 0
            self.now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.play_music(music_file)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(1000)
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            raise SystemExit

    def play_music(self,music_file):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)
            print "Music file %s loaded!" % music_file
        except pygame.error:
            print "File %s not found! (%s)" % (music_file, pygame.get_error())
            return
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            # check if playback has finished
            millis = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            # deltaMillis = self.t0[self.event_id].time * self.toSeconds * 1000
            deltaMillis = self.delays[self.event_id]
            # print millis,deltaMillis
            if millis - self.now >= deltaMillis:
                print self.t0[self.event_id].text
                self.event_id = (self.event_id + 1) % self.t0l
                self.now = millis
            clock.tick(30)

MIDIPlayer(music_file)
```

The timing of the messages I print based on the time converted to milliseconds looks much better. However, after a few seconds it still drifts.

Am I correctly converting MIDI ticks to milliseconds and keep track of passed milliseconds in the update while loop ?

This how the conversion is made:
        self.delays = []

```
    tempo = self.t[0][0].tempo
    ticks_per_beat = self.mid.ticks_per_beat

    last_event_ticks = 0
    microseconds = 0

    for event in self.t0:
        delta_ticks = event.time - last_event_ticks
        last_event_ticks = event.time
        delta_microseconds = tempo * delta_ticks / ticks_per_beat
        microseconds += delta_microseconds
        print event.text,microseconds/1000000.0
        self.delays.append(microseconds/1000)
```

and this is how the check if a 'cue' was encountered as time passes:

```
millis = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            deltaMillis = self.delays[self.event_id]
            if millis - self.now >= deltaMillis:
                print self.t0[self.event_id].text
                self.event_id = (self.event_id + 1) % self.t0l
                self.now = millis
            clock.tick(30)
```

I'm not sure if this implementation converts MIDI delta ticks to milliseconds incorrectly, incorrectly check if millisecond based delays pass or both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you have to merge all tracks, to ensure that the tempo change events are processed properly. (This is probably easier if you convert delta times to absolute tick values first; otherwise, you'd have to recompute the delta times whenever an event is inserted between events of another track.)

Then you have to compute, for each event, the relative time to the last event, like in the following pseudocode. It is important that the computation must use relative times because the tempo could have changed at any time:

```
tempo = 500000        # default: 120 BPM
ticks_per_beat = ...  # from the file header

last_event_ticks = 0
microseconds = 0
for each event:
    delta_ticks = event.ticks - last_event_ticks
    last_event_ticks = event.ticks
    delta_microseconds = tempo * delta_ticks / ticks_per_beat
    microseconds += delta_microseconds
    if event is a tempo event:
        tempo = event.new_tempo
    # ... handle event ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will try this in a bit. Just wanted to double check: is ```clocks_per_click``` the same as ```ticks_per_beat``` ? (I can't seem to find ```ticks_per_beat``` in the meta messages)

Comment: Time signature events are *not* needed to determine the time of events; they are useful only for notation. In Mido, the property that specifies ticks per beat is called `ticks_per_beat`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained very well. You can see the MIDI messages of the test MIDI file I'm using as text [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/Bee_Gees_-_Stayin_Alive-Voice.txt). It doesn't look like there is any message called ```ticks_per_beat```. Is it possible for a MIDI file to miss this information ? If so, what can be done ? Thank you(+1)

Comment: `ticks_per_beat` is not part of any message. That's what the comment says, and what the Mido documentation says.

Comment: I totally missed what you've been clearly explaining until now: there isn't a meta message with ticks_per_beat. This information is in the header and Mido already parses that. Thank you for making it obvious for me. I am now using ticks_per_beat, but I still seem to be a bit off over time, even though initially it looks pretty accurate.

Comment: How do you check that there is a tempos track ? Do you compute absolute times from delta times for all tracks ? How do you compute an absolute time from the delta times ? Do you insert the tempos track events into each track or do you merge all tracks together ?

Comment: @Stephane After merging, it does not matter from which track the tempo events come from. Yes. Add them up (per track). All tracks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to increase the frame rate. On my system, increasing `clock.tick(30)` to `clock.tick(300)` gives good results. You can measure this by printing how much your timing is off:

```
print self.t0[self.event_id].text, millis - self.now - deltaMillis
```

With 30 ticks the cues are lagging 20 to 30 millisecond behind. With 300 ticks they are at most 2 milliseconds behind. You might want to increase this even further.

Just to be safe you should run python with the `-u` switch to prevent `stdout` from buffering (this might be unnecessary, since lines end with newline).

I have a hard time determining the timing, but judging from the "Ah ha ha ha"'s it seems to be correct with these changes.

Comment: OMG! I was so close (yet so far) So simple! Thanks for breaking it down for me. I wouldn't have gotten here without CL. and your help